# The Help Center > Documentation page is empty

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, help-center, documentation

Navigating to [Help Center > Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation) shows a page without any content (just the regular headers, footers, etc.):

[image]

Comment: I have a 404 "Page Not Found" now. Probably went live sooner than wanted :).

Comment: @Tunaki You probably don't have access to docs at all, right? I see it still. Weird anyway.

Comment: @nicael Aah no, that would explain it, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The help center for Documentation will be available when the feature is launched to the general public. It was available on the doc-beta test site, but we can't move it to stackoverflow.com without also making it public to non-beta testers. That switch will be flipped "soon". (And not 6-8 weeks, soon. Sooner.)

Hang tight!